# What does this beach volleyball "hand motion" represent?

Tags: terminology, beach-volleyball

Was playing beach volleyball when the winning team's players started jokingly using their hands to symbolize sort of a mortar-and-pestle, with one hand grinding circularly in the other bowl-shaped one. They also said words like "grill" or "barbeque".

Does this have any particular meaning in volleyball circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the word "barbecue" definitly has a meaning in beachvolleyball. as tournaments used to be played in double-elimination-format, it meant that if you lost your first 2 games you have time for the barbecue. the saying was: "We lost one - two - barbecue" or to an opponent: "you'll go out of this tournament one - two - barbecue"

Answer (score -2):

No particular meaning that I'm aware of (and I'm a keen volleyball player, both beach and indoors). I'd guess it's just for "crushing them" or "grinding them down".

Comment: It's clearly an answer; you're not going to find evidence for negative answers. **And comments are to clarify the question, not for half answers**.